# Как сверстать такой блок с левый сплошным фоном и контентом по середине?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: Вёрстка]

Помогите сверстать такой блок.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, могу расписать что к чему)

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.block .left,
.block .right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block .left {
  padding-right: 110px;
  position: relative;
  background: khaki;
}


.block .right {
  padding-left: 110px;
}

.block .left::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ddd url('https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/png_detail/20180911/background-material-design-for-lorem-ipsum-logo-png_89690.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis, magna eu rutrum consequat, nibh enim ultrices massa, in laoreet arcu dui semper ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   Aenean eu lacus nec nisl convallis ultricies ac at est. Aenean pulvinar sem vel est varius fermentum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сложность в другом, там область контента 1100px, а серый фон, левого блока, начинается с начала экрана.

Comment: @user293437, обойти это можно кучей способов, через псевдоэлементы, через `box-shadow`, через дополнительные блоки.. В общем уйма решений.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто div, правые углы которого закруглили, добавили текст, и поверх наложили картинку поставив её справа, чтобы закругление div не было видно